# Oracle Regexp_Replace repetitive strings

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

Anyone help me tweak this pattern I need to capture repetitive strings next to each other (not other string apart) and keep only one of them. Here's my expression but I cannot get my desired output:

```
SELECT 
DATA,
REGEXP_REPLACE(DATA, '(.*)(.*)\1','\1\2') TRIMMED_STR
FROM
(
SELECT 'AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG' DATA FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB-CCC-CCC-AAA-BBB-BBB' DATA FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-AAA-CCC-DDD-DDD-EEE-AAA' DATA FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB' DATA FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-FFF-CCC' DATA FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-III-JJJ-DDD' DATA FROM DUAL
) STR


OLD 
AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG
AAA-BBB-CCC-CCC-AAA-BBB-BBB
AAA-AAA-CCC-DDD-DDD-EEE-AAA
AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB
AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-FFF-CCC
AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-III-JJJ-DDD

NEW
AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG
AAA-BBB-CCC-AAA-BBB
AAA-CCC-DDD-EEE-AAA
AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB
AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-CCC
AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-JJJ-DDD
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with str as
  2  (
  3  select 'AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG' data from dual
  4  union all
  5  select 'AAA-BBB-CCC-CCC-AAA-BBB-BBB' data from dual
  6  union all
  7  select 'AAA-AAA-CCC-DDD-DDD-EEE-AAA' data from dual
  8  union all
  9  select 'AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB' data from dual
 10  union all
 11  select 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-FFF-CCC' data from dual
 12  union all
 13  select 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-III-JJJ-DDD' data from dual
 14  )
 15  select data old,
 16    regexp_replace(data, '([^-]+)(-[-]*\1)+', '\1') new
 17  from str;

OLD                                                NEW
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG                                    AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG
AAA-BBB-CCC-CCC-AAA-BBB-BBB                        AAA-BBB-CCC-AAA-BBB
AAA-AAA-CCC-DDD-DDD-EEE-AAA                        AAA-CCC-DDD-EEE-AAA
AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB            AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB
AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-FFF-CCC                AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-CCC
AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-III-JJJ-DDD    AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-JJJ-DDD

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This solution can't be correct. The input `ABC-BCA` produces the output `ABCA`.

Comment: I presume (can't know, though) that actual data doesn't look like that. Maybe it is result of *unfortunate* concatenation of e.g. "Mick-Jill-Jill-Scott" which should then become "Mick-Jill-Scott". But, yes - you're absolutely right, @mathguy, if data really looked like you commented, it wouldn't work correctly for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT data,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         data,
         '(^|-)([^-]+)(-\2)+',
         '\1\2'
       ) AS trimmed_str
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (data) AS
  SELECT 'AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG'                                 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA-BBB-CCC-CCC-AAA-BBB-BBB'                     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA-AAA-CCC-DDD-DDD-EEE-AAA'                     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-FFF-CCC'             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-III-JJJ-DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA'                                 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | DATA | TRIMMED_STR |
> | --- | --- |
> | AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG | AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG |
> | AAA-BBB-CCC-CCC-AAA-BBB-BBB | AAA-BBB-CCC-AAA-BBB |
> | AAA-AAA-CCC-DDD-DDD-EEE-AAA | AAA-CCC-DDD-EEE-AAA |
> | AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB |
> | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-FFF-CCC | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-CCC |
> | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-III-JJJ-DDD | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-JJJ-DDD |
> | AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA | AAA |

---

If you can have terms that are variable length then you can use:

```sql
WITH bounds (rid, data, prev_pos, start_pos, end_pos) AS (
  SELECT ROWID, data, 1, 1, INSTR(data, '-', 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT rid, data, start_pos, end_pos + 1, INSTR(data, '-', end_pos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
),
terms (rid, data, start_pos, prev, term) AS (
  SELECT rid,
         data,
         start_pos,
         SUBSTR(data, prev_pos, start_pos - prev_pos - 1),
         CASE end_pos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(data, start_pos)
         ELSE SUBSTR(data, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos)
         END
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT MAX(data) AS data,
       LISTAGG(term, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY start_pos) AS trimmed_str
FROM   terms
WHERE  start_pos = 1
OR     prev <> term
GROUP BY rid
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT MAX(data) AS data,
       LISTAGG(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL),
         '-'
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL) AS trimmed_str
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 1
OR     REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL)
         <> REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL - 1)
CONNECT BY
       LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(data, '[^-]+')
AND    PRIOR ROWID = ROWID
AND    PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ROWID
```

Or, from Oracle 12:

```sql
SELECT data,
       trimmed_str
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(
                  REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL),
                  '-'
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL) AS trimmed_str
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  LEVEL = 1
         OR     REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL)
                  <> REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL - 1)
         CONNECT BY
                LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(data, '[^-]+')
       )
```

Which both output, for the above data and the additional row `AAA-AAA-AAA-AAABBB-BBB`:

> | DATA | TRIMMED_STR |
> | --- | --- |
> | AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG | AAA-BBB-FFF-GGG |
> | AAA-BBB-CCC-CCC-AAA-BBB-BBB | AAA-BBB-CCC-AAA-BBB |
> | AAA-AAA-CCC-DDD-DDD-EEE-AAA | AAA-CCC-DDD-EEE-AAA |
> | AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-BBB |
> | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-EEE-FFF-FFF-CCC | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-CCC |
> | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-III-JJJ-DDD | AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH-III-JJJ-DDD |
> | AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA | AAA |
> | AAA-AAA-AAA-AAABBB-BBB | AAA-AAABBB-BBB |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5a766712a6b120f25bad7d8c049c5626)*

Comment: thank you. I figured it out also REGEXP_REPLACE(DATA, '([^ ]{3}+)(-\1)+','\1') TRIMMED_STR https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c2483a5aadb0ebe8b7a0d5984ec47fe